# mysql container which is running on docker can't able to connect with spring boot java api service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

1. I have a mysql which is running on docker container. Using this command to pull and run container
2. $ docker container run --name **cloud** --network **employee** -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=bootdb -d mysql:5.7
3. spring boot application which is at local - i'm trying to establish a connection between java application and mysql container:

**Configuration Properties** :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://cloud/bootdb?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**Error:**

1. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: cloud
2. Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
   The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

although I have done everything to build that application by changing mysql connector version and mysql container version the same. couldn't make it to success. -

pom file configuration -

1. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
2. mysql-connector-java - version 5.1.46, docker mysql:5

Comment: You will need to expose the port and connect through localhost **or** put your Spring Boot application in a docker container as well and run it in the same network to be able to connect to the container that way.

Comment: hey!  @M.Deinum Thanks for your reply, I have done that part also but still getting error. to establish a connection between both containers caused:  it starts the connection and then after a min, it stopped. Note - while build the spring application it's showing build faliure,  without a jar fie i cant buid a image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say - Spring Boot app is running on your local - I assume it is running outside of docker.
Try following options

Step1 : Create mysql container again with exposed port : 3306

`docker run --name cloud --network employee -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=bootdb -d mysql:5.7`

Step2 : Verify using that mysql is running on the exposed port and you can access it. Take help from MY-SQL GUI tools.

Step3 : Update spring-boot configuration files.
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bootdb?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false`

Comment: Hi @fly2matrix Thanks for the reply, I have followed your steps and it worked!

Comment: Thank you. This part 
serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false 
allowed me to access mysql-5.7.x from docker